# OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've tried making this little thing where if the player clicks it shoots, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag != "player" || col.gameObject.tag != "fireball")
    {
        Debug.Log(col.gameObject.tag);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

This code is meant to be if the col isn't equal to player or fireball it destroys the gameObject and debugs the `col`'s tag.

But it destroys when it enters the player, and it also destroys when hitting the fireball.
The fireball and it's children are called "fireball" and the player and children are called "player", it still destroys the fireball gameObject.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if statement will always be true, as the tag will always be not "player" or not "fireball".

If you want it to not destroy if the tag is "player" or if the tag is "fireball", you will need to change your if statement to use && instead like so:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag != "player" && col.gameObject.tag != "fireball")
    {
        Debug.Log(col.gameObject.tag);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, but why doesn't || work?

Comment: || is an "OR" statement while "&&" is an "AND" statement. Lets say you collide with the player, the first condition will return false as its the player but the second condition returns true because it isn't a fireball. Because one of the conditions is satisfied, the OR statement returns true. OR statements only require one condition to return true where as AND conditions require all the given conditions to return true.